# Best way to remove a substring from a string

Tags: c#, string

I have several strings like this:

```
 string x = "[{\"Name\":\"property1\",\"Value\":true},{\"Name\":\"FOO\",\"Value\":12345ddddeeee},{\"Name\":\"property3\",\"Value\":false}]";
```

And need to remove

```
"{\"Name\":\"FOO\",\"Value\":12345ddddeeee}"
```

From the original string. However, that FOO name+value can lie anywhere in the string. It doesn't necessarily have to be between property1 and property3. What would be the best way to remove it from a generic string of the same format as x?

The Value for FOO can vary

Comment: Sorry, the Value for FOO can vary

Comment: What is it about that string that makes it removal-worthy? How can you identify it? By name?

Comment: Yes just via the "Name" which would be FOO. I need to remove the Value after that

Comment: And is just parsing the JSON out of the question?

Comment: No, it's not out of the question.

Comment: I don't think it's quite valid JSON because `12345ddddeeee` isn't a number and isn't quoted. But perhaps it was anonymized incorrectly. Is that the case, SKLAK?

Comment: @31eee384 That is not the case. It in fact doesn't have quotes around it.

Comment: Unfortunate. Should note that in the question, because otherwise it does look a lot like json. On another note, I don't think you've answered Matthew's other question: what marks a name-value pair in a way that you want to delete `Value`? If the name can vary, wouldn't you really want to get rid of all three `Value`s? Or do you just mean that `Name` can be *specified*, so you can choose which `Value` to remove?

Comment: I want to remove the Value that comes after the Name, "FOO". That Name has to be in the string at some point followed by a Value that would be the key which I need to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way:

```
string tobesearched = "{\"Name\":\"FOO\",\"Value\":";
string k = x.Substring(x.IndexOf(tobesearched));

string final = x.Replace(x.Substring(x.IndexOf(tobesearched), x.IndexOf(tobesearched) + k.IndexOf("}") - x.IndexOf(tobesearched)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please validate and fix your json. You can use something like [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

If you can parse the string yourself and search for Name `FOO` that might be the best way. But then you have to take care of all the parsing related tasks, say for example unnecessary empty spaces in the json string.

If this `string x` is not too big (I leave it to you to do the profiling to determine what is too big for your program) then I would suggest deserializing the `string` in to a `List`, removing unnecessary data and serializing back might be easy. See sample code given below. You need to call `ParseString()` method to get the task done. Please note that you have to update this as per your needs.

```
public class ParseMyDateItemList
{
    public static void ParseString()
    {
        string x = "[{\"Name\":\"property1\",\"Value\":true},{\"Name\":\"FOO\",\"Value\":\"12345ddddeeee\"},{\"Name\":\"property3\",\"Value\":false}]";
        var dataItems = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<MyDataItem>>(x);
        var resultDataItems = dataItems.Except(dataItems.Where(t => t.Name.ToLower() == "foo")).ToList();
        var resultJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultDataItems);

    }
}

public class MyDataItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the strings. Some of the values aren't in quotes, therefore not in the correct JSON format. The string in the original question is correct and you can see some of the values aren't quoted.

Comment: I was trying to update my answer above by handling the parsing errors in `DeserializeObject`. But it looks like the Newtonsoft is not doing it as required in your case. So I think my answer is not correct.